R Shiny + MongoDB works locally but not shinyapps.io, why?
I am building a Shiny app which pulls data from a MongoDB Atlas cluster, and locally everything runs smoothly, but soon as I publish on shinyapps.io, the app immediately crashes, and the logs report the error "No suitable servers found". From what I can gather, this problem has been experienced by others in the past, but seems to have been worked itself out (see this question). Does anybody have insight on the matter? Thanks in advance.
